# VS 2012 workspace can't be loaded in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

I have a default workspace already created when setting up solution in VS 2012.
Part of the folder structure contains SSRS reports which needs to be opened in VS 2008.

**Folder structure:**

```
D:\TFS\Products\ - current workspace mapping  
D:\TFS\Products\Portal\Portal.sln - this is the solution I open in VS 2012  
D:\TFS\Products\Reports\Reports.sln - this is the solution I want to open in VS 2008
```

I am facing workspace related issues while trying to open SSRS report solution in VS 2008 - When I load Visual Studio 2008, I get this error -

```
Team Foundation Error - The workspace xxx;myname already exists on computer xxx.
```

I click OK for above error and get similar error when trying to access the report solution using
File -> 'Open from Source Control'.

Why I am not able to open the report solution in VS 2008 from existing workspace?

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved above issue by changing workspace type in VS 2012 from 'local' to 'server' type as suggested in this post -

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/065f622e-5a38-4acb-bbd3-87b83697b8eb/same-workspace-for-vs2010-and-vs2013?forum=tfsgeneral#cfd7977f-a083-4169-aad2-99aaf30170d6